# What path should I provide for imagecreatefrompng in separate folders joomla?

Tags: php, url, joomla, path, imagecreatefrompng

I've been trying to make use of the function `imagecreatefrompng` in joomla.
Iam using that function inside components/mycomponent/views/imgview/tmpl/default.php
I have to pass the image url administrator/components/mycomponent/images/img.png into it.

I've tried many ways. But none of it is working. Is there any specific way to pass the url to that function.
ie. should I pass it as

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('administrator/components/mycomponent/images/img.png');
```

or

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('http://localhost/joomla/administrator/components/mycomponent/images/img.png');
```

or

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('/var/www/joomla/administrator/components/mycomponent/images/img.png');
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd definitely want to use a path, not an URL. And can you concretize any errors you receive when trying to use one of those invocations?

Comment: Prepend the path $config property rather than hard coding.

Comment: @mario: trying out as you said.

Comment: @Elin: I'll eventually have to add the configuration paths. but hardcoding it now to check whether it works for now...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at some of the default template files, Joomla typically prefers you to make use of the `JPATH_ROOT` global variable to make sure you're always working from the site root, like so:

```
$path = JPATH_ROOT . '/administrator/components/mycomponent/images/img.png';  
$img = imagecreatefrompng($path);
```

EDIT: Forgot the first slash.